# Flag declined, needs another look

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

This 5-½ year old answer only contains a link, which is now dead, and a very generic name "jQuery Validator" plugin.   Since the name can refer to any number of different plugins and the link is dead, the answer is no longer useful.  In addition, it did not really answer the OP's question in the first place, which was about a very specific plugin that does not have the desired feature.

[Validate inputs that are not inside a form with jQuery Validation plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487430/validate-inputs-that-are-not-inside-a-form-with-jquery-validation-plugin/487690#487690)

Because of the dead link, there is nothing else useful for the reader in this answer and I think it needs to be removed.  I cannot flag it again to explain anything since my original "not an answer" flag was declined.

Why is such an old question relevant?  Because the same question has been asked many times and this one might be considered as a matching candidate when closing the newer ones as duplicates.

---

Even with a good link, the answer still does not properly address the OP which was titled: *"Validate inputs that are not inside a form with **jQuery Validation plugin**"*.

This supports the point made by @mario in the comments below:

> *"The actual question is if tool-recommendation answers without further reasoning are useful"*

---

Adding to the confusion, a few hours after I posted this Meta question, somebody came along and edited the link in the answer to match the plugin the OP was asking about.

Original Link in answer:  http://plugins.jquery.com/project/validator

As per Wayback machine:  http://web.archive.org/web/20100217045419/http://plugins.jquery.com/project/validator

Translates into this:  http://code.google.com/p/jquery-validator/

This plugin, last updated in January 2009, is NOT [the jQuery Validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org) as per the OP.

Comment: Dead links can be fixed, http://web.archive.org/web/20100217045419/http://plugins.jquery.com/project/validator. The actual question is if tool-recommendation answers without further reasoning are useful.

Comment: Isn't the question OT as searching for a resource ..etc.

Comment: @mario, that didn't really fix anything as the archived page is still almost 6 years old and the download links to the actual plugin are still dead.

Comment: @bummi, the OP was tagged with and asking about a specific plugin.

Comment: The homepage link still works however; references http://code.google.com/p/jquery-validator/

Comment: @mario, fair enough... but it's still a jQuery plugin last updated more than five years ago... the answer is essentially useless. If the point of SO is to maintain a repository of high quality Q&A, then this one is a failure.

Comment: After your last edit and from the fact that this answer was accepted, either the question could be seen as tool requestion or the one who is searching is still able to find was he is looking for in the plugin section of the opening site. Since I'm not familiar with jquery I can't judge which plugin was meant.

Comment: @bummi, The OP was specifically asking about the jQuery Validate plugin as per his title and his tag.  This plugin mandates a `<form>` element.  The answer was pointing to a totally different plugin, which apparently does not mandate a `<form>` element.  Your confusion about the plugin(s) proves my point that this is a very poor answer.

Comment: Not sure what the delete threshold is since it has upvotes, but it will probably only take 4-5 10Ker's to vote to delete.  If you feel that strongly, then see if you can find enough.  You are one so you only need 3 to 4 more (assuming you haven't voted to delete yourself)

Comment: `I cannot flag it again to explain anything since my original "not an answer" flag was declined.` Am I interpreting this correctly to say you flagged this as "Not an Answer"?

Comment: It's jQuery - nobody cares.

Comment: @psubsee2003, other than calling attention to it here on Meta, how exactly would I gather the required delete votes?  (No, the "delete" link is not available to me.)

Comment: @Sparky now that you mention it, we probably need some downvotes first, then the delete link will show up.  But chat is a common place to find help when you need it.

Comment: @psubsee2003, oh I see.  Never used chat for anything except extended commenting with an OP.

Answer (score 12):

If I read your question correctly, your problem is you flagged it as "Not an Answer" and expected the moderator to read your mind.  Do not use "Not an Answer" flags when the answer is obvious an **attempt** to answer the question.  For future reading on proper use of "Not an Answer" flags, please read the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) post [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer)

Additionally, as much as you want to profess that it doesn't answer the OP's question, that argument  gets rendered completely invalid when the OP accepted it an the answer.  The reason this is relavant is not because of the quality of the answer, but because you are claiming it doesn't answer the OP's question.  How could it not answer the OP's question if they OP accepted it?  The moderator is going to look at things like that when considering the flag.

Moderators have virtually zero context when reviewing flags and usually will not be familiar with the technologies in the post to make an informed judgement, so when they see the "not an answer" flag on a post that looks like an answer, they will decline it.

Instead, select "other" and **explain** exactly what you think should be done and why.  If given the proper context as you have described here, I have a feeling they would have acted differently, or at least provided a better explanation in the decline message as to why they disagreed.

Comment: As far as my argument getting rendered invalid because the OP "accepted" it:  SO is not so much about satisfying one particular individual as it is about being a high quality repository of Q & A.  The act of "accepting" does not magically turn a poor or disconnected answer into something that helps the rest of the community.

Comment: I don't expect the moderator to read my mind, but since it was a link-only answer, I figured that it was pretty self-explanatory.  In my defense, I've flagged accepted answers like this before, and moderators have indeed deleted them when they've only contained a link.

Comment: @Sparky every moderator is different, but the message from the SE team in the past has been don't use Not an Answer for stuff that is an attempt to answer.  Flagging as such may have worked in the past, but it failed this time.  The general rule of thumb I use is if it isn't completely obvious what the problem is simply by looking at it, you should use other and explain.

Comment: I honestly flagged for the link-only aspect and only started exploring the link in depth later.  Then when I wanted to explain more, I couldn't because I had already flagged it.  I suppose I could have flagged the question itself with "other", but decided to take this to Meta instead.

Comment: note that this answer is certainly not a link-only answer. It does tell in the actual answer what is the suggested way to go, and the answer would've worked even without the link, link was just an added help.

Comment: @eis, I think you too may have misunderstood the answer.  How does the answer work without the link?  Without the obsolete plugin at the link, the OP cannot achieve what he's asking.  (Note: the OP is asking about a plugin that is NOT the same plugin linked in the answer)

Comment: @eis, I see now why you thought this answer was relevant without the link.  Somebody came along and changed the link into [the jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org) plugin.  However, as per the original link posted in the answer, that is not the same plugin.  Additionally, the answer would be factually incorrect since the [the jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org) plugin cannot validate a form without a `form` container.  As per @mario's research in the comments, the answer was originally linking to this plugin:  http://code.google.com/p/jquery-validator/

Comment: Please don't demand that I _"drop an argument"_, especially when that's not even the argument I'm making.  The answer is obsolete garbage and having a green checkmark doesn't change that.

Comment: @Sparky the answer sucks now, yes, and should be downvoted and hopefully deleted.  But I said that because you keep bringing up as a reason that the answer sucks.  It doesn't suck for that reason.  It sucks because it is a link to a tool, with a vague description of the tool, and the tool is dead.

Comment: _"It sucks because it is a link to a tool, with a vague description of the tool, and the tool is dead."_  LOL... isn't that what I've been saying?  I think you're hung up on my original flag which admittedly was not correct.

Comment: For the record, I understand and agree with 95% of what everyone on this page has said.  I was just looking for a good way to improve this question, not devolve into an argument over semantics.

Comment: @Sparky `<removes foot from mouth>` you know what I completely misread a sentence in your previous comment.  I think we are on the same page here now.  I removed the comment in question since it was based on a false premise

Comment: @Sparky you didn't address one of my points in my deleted inflammatory comment... you can try flagging it again properly with an "other" flag.  Or did you do that already?

Comment: No, it will not allow me to flag it again... that's why I posted here in Meta.  I get the _"you have already flagged"_ error, even though the original flag was addressed.

Comment: @Sparky "other" flags don't have that restriction unless something has changed.  The only restriction was you can't raise another "other" flag until the first was handled

Comment: I understand, although that's what's happening.  I selected "other" _after_ my original flag was declined and it was rejected with the _"you have already flagged"_ message.

Comment: I know what happened.  After a fairly long run of "accepted" flags, two unrelated flags were declined recently (not even two in a row), so now I'm blocked from using the "other" reason flag on any question or answer.

Comment: I don't think it really needs to be flagged anyway, we as the community can handle this with downvotes and delete votes.

Comment: @Kevin Correct. I suggested that action in the question comments. But at the time I wrote this, the answer was +4 andit is not that easy to delete a positively scored old answer

Comment: But at the same time, the answer *does* answer the question. it's valid, even if old. Looking through the source, i don't even see any glaring problems that would make it not work in the latest version. it isn't performing ajax, it isn't dealing with properties using .attr, looks pretty clean as far as staying away from methods that have changed drastically over the years.

Comment: It is of course unfortunate that it uses the same name as the most popular jQuery form validation plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Thin ice for me since not familiar with the matter(me). The plugin he was asking for seems not have the abilities he was asking for, another one seem to have them, so he accepted the answer, from the upvotes at least on other person did find it useful. The plugin can still be found with the link and linkdescripion  provided. I don't think that the fact that the provided answer offered a different solution could be a reason to remove it.

Comment: I think the fact that the plugin hasn't been touched in 6 years old, essentially a dead project (and likely will not work with today's jQuery), has to weigh into the matter here.  After all, if we're trying to maintain a high quality repository, while this may have been an awesome answer in 2009, it's a very poor answer today.  That's all besides the fact this is a "link-only" answer, something we're always trying to avoid.

Comment: I'm not happy with this too, but it was accepted, is findable and if we should want  to cleanup all old answers it would be never ending and would not be fair for those who provided solutions. Link only would fit IIRC answers not libraries.

Comment: Saying that it's "never ending" is not a good argument to do nothing.  Every single thing we do here from correcting spelling, re-tagging, closing duplicates, etc... these are all "never ending" tasks that maintain the high quality of this site.  The answer is poor (both for being a link-only answer that sidestepped the question and for being horribly outdated) and if we want to maintain the high quality of this site, then it should be deleted or at least down-voted.

Comment: I still think the deleted answer better answers the question than Sparky's answer. Sparky's answer simply says it can't be done with plugin x, find another plugin, whereas the deleted answer gives plugin y where it *does* work, therefore actually solving the problem rather than just saying it can't be done with plugin x. Maybe the two answers should be combined to form a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is such an old question relevant? Because the same question has
>   been asked many times and this one might be considered as a matching
>   candidate when closing the newer ones as duplicates.

I see you've already marked some other threads as duplicates of this one, making handling of this question even more important.

So I would suggest this:

Answer this question with a better answer - an answer telling that plugin OP uses cannot be used that way, and what are the alternatives, preferrably with usage examples. That'll probably get the upvotes and, the way I see it, solve the problem.

I see no need for moderator flags here. The answer there actually helped OP and provided him direction on were to go, and even without the link, it would've been useful. If the accepted answer no longer works, you should just provide a better answer. We should not delete old answers just because we can do better today, we should post better ones.

Comment: I agree with most of what you said here.  However, how would this answer have been useful without the link?  Take away the link and all that's left is mention of a plugin that would be nearly impossible to find.

Comment: Picking this one as the source for other duplicates was done without close enough inspection of the accepted answer.  Therefore, I will work on posting a better answer to this question.

Comment: @Sparky take away the link and you still have an answer telling you that you can do what you want using another plugin, and tells the name of that plugin. It's certainly useful information. Link helps, but the answer works without it as well. A link-only answer is an answer that does not help at all without the link, such as "[take a look, this is how it is solved](http://non-working-link.invalid)"

Comment: I'm not saying it's a good answer, but it's not a link-only answer, and it is an answer.

Comment: Anyway, I'm doing my best here.  I posted a new answer and I corrected the link in the accepted answer to match the plugin the original answer was linked to.

Comment: Let's get the heart of the matter... the high quality repository is getting lost when we cannot see obsolete as obsolete and do something about it.